# Find Missing Letter in List (Lowercase or Uppercase, Exclusively)

Tags: python, alphabet

Input is a list, consistently lower or uppercase. Within the sequence, when sorted correctly, one letter is missing. The function should return the missing letter as string output. See code below, where you'll notice I'm halfway done having calculated the missing letter just for lowercase lists.

```
import string 
def find_missing_letter(chars):
    for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if letter not in chars:
            return letter[0]
```

Test examples:

```
test.assert_equals(find_missing_letter(['a','b','c','d','f']), 'e')
test.assert_equals(find_missing_letter(['O','Q','R','S']), 'P')
```

Anyone know how to check regardless of letter case??

Comment: You're not halfway done - that doesn't work properly for lowercase either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 changes are required for your specification:

1. Determine your charset by checking for the type of the letters `chars` contains.
2. Start your check from the character that is the head of `chars` - that way chacking for `b, c, e` will result in `d` and not `a`.

Should go like:

```
def find_missing_letter(chars):
    charset = string.ascii_lowercase if chars[0] >= 'a' else string.ascii_uppercase
    for letter in charset[charset.index(chars[0]):]:
        if letter not in chars:
            return letter[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Irrespective of lowercase or uppercase, this should work. It can even work for other consecutive sequences.

```
def missing_elements(L):
    start, end = L[0], L[-1]
    return sorted(set(range(start, end + 1)).difference(L))

def find_missing_letter(chars):
    numbers = list(map(ord, chars))
    n = missing_elements(numbers)
    return chr(n[0])
```

Test Example:

```
chars = ['a','b', 'd']
print(find_missing_letter(chars))
```

Output:

> c

Comment: +1! Nice trick. But why did you use numbers? You may use letters directly. set() is not limited to numbers.

Comment: This is because I'm using range to get all consecutive values. And I appreciate the upvote. :D

Comment: Yes-yes, but you didn't have to do it with range(). Am I not correct. Also, are you sure you included all lower and upper cases this way? You used start and end, but what if input isn't sorted? What if it is sorted in ascending order?

Comment: BTW: I highly value creativity. Therefore it is +1. Also your code has potential speed improvement over original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def find_missing (txt):
    """Takes string or other type of iterable containing letters.
    Returns a list of all letters that aren't present in the input string/iterable.
    Missing letters are returned as lower case.
    """
    txt = (x.lower() for x in txt if x.isalpha()) # Generator object
    found = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)
    for x in txt: found[x] = 1
    return [x for x in found if found[x]==0]
```

Comment: This makes only one pass through all chars +one and a half  through all ascii. Your way passes through all ascii and over and over through all chars. Each time the letter is not in chars whole chars are traversed, and always some of them. I am talking about operator in. When you say "<something>" in list([<some_iterable>]) in iterates over iterable to check if "<something>" is in there or not. So, my code should be a little faster for bigger chars where letters might repeat themselves a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string module and string find method to locate the missing letter.
Where

> find()

method return -1 if the letter/word is missing in a string.

```
import string
input_str=raw_input()
output_str=""

for letter in string.letters:

    if input_str.find(letter) ==-1:
        output_str=output_str+letter

print output_str
```

Answer (score 0):

Codewars Excercise

```
import string
def find_missing_letter(char):
    if char[0] in string.ascii_lowercase:
        num=string.ascii_lowercase.index(chars[0])
        for letters in string.ascii_lowercase[num:num+len(chars)+1]:
            if letters not in chars:
                return letters
    elif chars[0] in string.ascii_uppercase:
        num=string.ascii_uppercase.index(chars[0])
        for letters in string.ascii_uppercase[num:num+len(chars)+1]:
            if letters not in chars:
                return letters
```